# convert std object class to comma seperated string

Tags: php, stdclass

I have an std class object from twitter and i would like to take the ids array values and put them in a php variable $ids where `$ids = (15761916,30144785,382747195,19399719)`.

I imagine using a for loop and using phps implode but i'm not sure how to go about it.

```
stdClass Object
(
  [ids] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15761916
        [1] => 30144785
        [2] => 382747195
        [3] => 19399719

    )

  [next_cursor] => 0
  [next_cursor_str] => 0
  [previous_cursor] => 0
  [previous_cursor_str] => 0
)
```

Comment: Whats your desired result?

Comment: Comma separated string, as in the title.

Comment: $ids = (15761916,30144785,382747195,19399719)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ids = "(" . implode(",", $object->ids) . ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way, I don't know if this will work (sorry!) as I don't tend to use a lot of stdClass Objects like this... would be to use an array map...

```
$ids = function (stdClass Object $object) {
  return implode (",", $object->ids);
};
```

Maybe something like that, not entirely sure if this is the correct syntax... on my phone at the moment. Give that a shot!

I made it a lambda function by habbit you could just as easily do:

```
$ids = implode (",", $object->ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function to convert into array

```
$vars = get_object_vars ( $Obj );
print_r ( $vars );
$ids = implode (",", $vars[ids]);
```

Comment: one wants the values of the array as a comma separated strings not all the vars.

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov no need to say sorry, in the field of programming discussion must be made to clear understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As an extended answer u have 2 options :)

1st is implementing the [Serializable Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) by doing so u can use the serialize function to get the desired output:

```
public function serialize() {
    return array_implode(',', $this->ids);
}
```

OR

```
public function __toString() {
    return array_implode(',', $this->ids);
}
```

and the usage becomes :

1. Serializable:

   serialize($object_instance);
2. __toString:

   print $object_instance;

both will give u the desired output, so u dont need to add the extra overhead to use a function or use `array_implode()` in inline scripts.